# Upgrade Gulp 3 to Gulp 4 - gulp.start.apply

Tags: gulp

I have an existing launch.js and gulpfile.js created for Node6/Gulp3 which I need to upgrade to Node14/Gulp4.

Can anyone please guide if I have upgraded call to `gulp.start.apply` correctly -
Existing snippet from launch.js in Gulp3 -

```
var tasks = argv._;
var toRun = tasks.length ? tasks : ['default'];
...
require("./gulpfile.js");
...
var gulpInst = require("gulp");
gulpInst.start.apply(gulpInst, toRun);
```

I have tried changing last line of code to following - but I am not able to run the task -

```
gulpInst.task('default', gulpInst.series(toRun[0], function(done) { done(); }));
```

'dev' and 'prod' are two tasks defined in gulpfile.js. So, I am calling launch.js from command prompt as -

> node launch.js dev

but no task is run :(

Have I updated `gulp.start.apply` with correct code for Gulp4?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if someone else looking for answer -
Here is how I was able to run the task in Gulp 4 -

```
gulpInst.task(toRun)();
```

where '`toRun`' is the task that needs to be run.

HTH.